# Seeing The Wood For The Trees

Tags: sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation

North & Hillard Ex. 190; Q1: "While they were cutting down the wood the enemy came upon them."
The answer: "dum silvam succidunt eos hostis adoritur."
The instruction given by N & H, p.146: dum (= while) regularly takes present indicative, even of past time.

Firstly: "were cutting down" must be imperfect yet the answer gives the perfect "succidunt"--why?
This sometimes occurs when the following verb is pluperf; but, then, these are completed actions, in the past.
Secondly: dum (= while) governs "succidunt"; so, from N-&-H's instruction the writer could choose to put this in the present tense; but, not "adoritur"--which is in the present?
Thirdly: "adoritur" means "he attacks"; perfectly valid in the circumstances given, in the Q, but the student is asked for "came upon them"--assuming that this is acceptable artistic license?

Answer (score 5):

1. *Succidunt* is present, not perfect, which would be *succiderunt*. Present and perfect stem are identical for this verb, but in this case the difference is visible in the present ending *-unt*. so the present indicative is used after *dum* as per the instruction.
2. *Adoritur* should probably be read as *[praesens historicum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)*. You could use a past tense instead.
3. I would say *attacked* and *came upon* are both fine, with a similar meaning. From Lewis & Short:

> **adorior:** ... *to rise up for the purpose of going to some one or something*, or *of undertaking something great, difficult*, or *hazardous* (clandestinely, artfully, when a hostile approach is spoken of; while *aggredi* indicates a direct, open attack from a distance ...)

Comment: present tense, of course it is! Get "blind spots" over things; most notably, indirect speech cf epistemic modality. Thank you.

Comment: @tony: Happens to all of us from time to time!